# How to serve files from outside context using Tapestry5

Tags: java, tapestry

I'm a little stuck here.

I would like to store some files specific to users which can be served (as embedded objects). These files are in a known location and the filename will be known. If I store these files within the context e.g ${context:/files}/abc.pdf then I have a working solution but the issue is that they are then accessible to anyone if they know the address.

I would therefore like to store them in for example:
c:/tapestry5/userfiles/

However, now I can no longer in my .tml build up a path for the embedded object. The previous solution looks like this:

```
<object width="100%" height="750px" type="application/pdf" data="${context:/exercises}${fileUrlWithinContext}" id="pdf_content">
    <p>The PDF cannot be displayed, please update your browser.</p>
</object>
```

So, my question is - If I have them stored outside of the context, how can I serve them so that they can be embedded on a page?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I will answer this myself for anyone else looking.

The solution is to create a page which returns a StreamResponse from onActivate. You can then use the link to that page as the resource, and you can put the logic in that page to go and fetch the file from wherever it is and return it as a StreamResponse.